# Print values in jasper ireport horizontally

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to print data in following format in ireport 4.5

```
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31   Total

     B0815 ASHOK KUMAR (MACHINE OPERATOR)

     12.0 23.23 108 597.23 201.10 110 111 0 0 0 0 12.80 15.10


     B1232 T.RAO (HEM OPERATOR)

     0 0 320.12 123.30 32.90 ..........



    where 1,2,3,4..... 31 are days of the month
    B0815 = employee id
    ASHOK KUMAR =  employee name
    MACHINE OPERATOR = designation
    12.0 23.23 108 597.23 201.10 110 111 are amount for that day respectively.
```

How to print data horizontally day-wise. And break on change in employee token. I have following fields from my database table: `<EmpId,Name,Designation,Day,Amount>`

Comment: Could you please post your table structure ?

Comment: @Fahad 
Table Structure :

EmpId varchar2(5)

EmpName varchar2(20)

Designation varchar2(10)

Amount bigdecimal

dt date

day bigdecimal

have used "extract(day from dt) as day" to get the days of the month

Comment: I think,  you should use cross tab. Why are you using ireport 4.5. Why not latest one.

Comment: @FahadAnjum thanks it worked using crosstab. The only issue is now, the  page header that I am putting with report title and company report is not printing on every page. I have put the cross tab in the summary section and there are 18 pages generated. I wish I could get the page header printed on every page.

Comment: Have you set property Summary with page header and page footer ? If not add that property. Have you used title or page header band ?

Comment: Your question is unclear, try to format your post, show the data you have and the desired output. If you tried something include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved thanks to @Fahad Anjum.

- I have a pageheader with company logo and title of report.
- CrossTab report at the summary band.
- Have turned on "Summary with page header and footer"

[image: REPORT PAGE2]

It has solved my purpose for the time-being. The only issue though not so important is that I am getting extra blank pages at the first and last of the report. After searching for the solution I got to know that it is because of some extra space after the crosstab report in the summary band. But when I expand it to cover the whole band I get java heap space error... after running for a long time.

I have changed the structure though so that I don't get stuck in one task. Initially my intention was to get

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31   Total

B0815 ASHOK KUMAR (MACHINE OPERATOR)

12.0 23.23 108 597.23 201.10 110 111 0 0 0 0 12.80 15.10 12 221.0 21.4 11 42 42 64 75.5       4232.33

B0823 VISHAL YADAV (MACHINE OPERATOR)

12.0 23.23 108 597.23 201.10 110 111 0 0 0 0 12.80 15.10 12 221.0 21.4 11 42 42 64 75.5       4232.33